# How to add text at the end of a line containing a string with a pattern in a text file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, terminal

For example:

```
hello1.jpg
hello2.jpg
hello3.jpg
```

I would like to edit it so that it is like this:

```
hello1.jpg 0
hello2.jpg 0
hello3.jpg 0
```

I have tried:

```
sed -i '/(hello*)/ s/$/ 0/' hello.txt
perl -ipe 's/$/ 0/ if /hello/' hello.txt
sed -i '/^hello*/ s/$/ 0/' hello.txt
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first approach was almost correct, aside from the fact that the parentheses (which aren't needed) were being interpreted literally:

```
$ sed '/hello/ s/$/ 0/' file
hello1.jpg 0
hello2.jpg 0
hello3.jpg 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the globs or other `*` uses in your sed command.  The following works for me:

```
sed -e '/hello/ s/$/ 0/' hello.txt
```

and you can use the `-i` (with GNU) once you're sure that works for you

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/hello/{print $0" "0}' filename
```